# Score system for number of clicks, socket.io and Javascript

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an application and I am counting the clicks on an object client side, sending to the server

```
   socket.emit('playerScore',score);
```

Pushing to an array server side

```
    socket.on('playerScore',function(data){ 
    socket.score = data;
    score.push(socket.score);
```

Then sending back to the clients

```
    io.sockets.emit ('scores',score);
```

But it receives the score once from each client, and sends it back to the clients once for each client. I am trying to compare the score sent from the client on the server side and send back the highest number to compare to the local score the client already has. But I'm sending it more than once and my filter doesn't seem to work.

```
var scoreData = data;
      var largest = scoreData[0];
for (var i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    if (largest < scoreData[i] ) {
        largest = scoreData[i];
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You wan't all the users to recieve the highest score?

Comment: Yea all the users to receive the highest score, that way they can compare to their own score stored locally?

Comment: I don't understand what where you're sending it more than once, can you provide full code?

Comment: The server receives a score for each client, and stores it into an array then sends the array to the connected clients. But if the server receives 2 scores from the clients it will send the array twice once with one score and the second time with both scores.

Comment: That's how sockets work. If you want a workaround, you can wait when you recieve a score, and instead of sending the score back immediatly, send them periodically, with a timeout, if you like that, I can post an answer.

Comment: I am just struggling to share the highest score with all connected client. I just need a way to either only send the highest score or filter the highest score out of the array on the client side. So I can compare it to show whos score was the highest.

Comment: Ah you want to send only the highest score, not at the same time all the scores, that's more clear now ;)

Comment: haha yea, i just need the highest score. If i console.log an empty score array on the server side with three clients:
[ 0 ]
[ 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0 ]

Comment: Check my answer. I only send the highest score.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only pass the highest score (from server to client) instead of the entire array. With the highest score, your client can check if he has it stored locally.

But maybe you could have a better approach to this:

1. Your array could have:

   {
       socketId: '123123',
       score: 12
   }
2. When the server receives a score, push the score and socketId
3. Get the object from array with the highest score
4. Pass it to all clients

With this, your client-side could compare direcly by id, instead of by score.

Comment: Hey, yea your first sentence is what im trying to achieve but i cannot figure it out. With @Marcos Casagrande help i have got it working client side. But i am still receiving multiple score from the server

Answer (score 0):

**Server:**

```
var scores = [];

function getHighest(arr){
    var highest = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (highest < arr[i] ) {
            highest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return highest;
}



socket.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('join', function(data) {
        client.join("scores"); // Join socket IO Room
    });

    client.on('playerScore', function(data){ 
        scores.push(data);
        //Send to all users in scores room
        socket.in("scores").emit('scores', getHighest(scores)); 
    });
});
```

**In the client:**

```
socket.emit("join"); //Join Room
socket.emit("playerScore", score);

socket.on("scores", function(highest){ 
   if(highest > myScore) console.log("Do something");
});
```

Comment: With this I still receive three variables from the server?

Comment: I supposed that score in scores.push(score); is just a single score, what type of data are you sending to "playerScore"?

Comment: Each client sends their score, so scores.push(score) will receive a score for every connected client. The filtering on the client side works. I send an alert if to say if they won or not. But I send how ever many clients are connected in alerts to each socket. e.g. 2 sockets connected = 2 alerts for each socket comparing the send score to their own score

Comment: It is just a variable, but sent once by each client

Comment: Your question wasn't very clear, check my new answer using socket io rooms.